# ZF3: How to route to specific controller/action based on method and route?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route, zend-framework3, zend-router

In my module's `module.config.php`, I have something like this:

```
namespace Application;

return [
    //...
    // myroute1 will route to IndexController fooAction if the route is matching '/index/foo' but regardless of request method
    'myroute1' => [
        'type' => Zend\Router\Http\Literal::class,
        'options' => [
            'route'    => '/index/foo',
            'defaults' => [
                'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                'action'     => 'foo',
            ],
        ],
    ],

    // myroute2 will route to IndexController fooAction if the route is request method is GET but regardless of requested route
    'myroute2' => [
        'type'    => Zend\Router\Http\Method::class,
        'options' => [
            'verb'     => 'get',
            'defaults' => [
                'controller'    => Controller\IndexController::class,
                'action'        => 'foo',
            ],
        ],
    ],
    //...
];
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

- If route **/index/foo** is requested AND is requested by **GET** method, then it should be routed to *IndexController* *fooAction*
- If route **/index/foo** is requested AND is requested by **POST** method, then it should be routed to *IndexController* ***bar***Action (notice it's barAction here not fooAction)

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the literal to a `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Part` route, and then putting the HTTP routes in as CHILD routes!

See here https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-router/routing/#http-route-types

Comment: That's what I was looking for. But I noticed it's mentioned "`Part` routes are not meant to be used directly".

Answer (score 2):

A note to myself and anyone else looking, as additional note to @delboy1978uk's answer.

The answer I was looking for is something like this:

- GET `/index/foo` => IndexController fooAction
- POST `/index/foo` => IndexController barAction

So the code in `module.config.php` file can be like this:

```
return [
    //...
    'myroute1' => [// The parent route will match the route "/index/foo"
        'type' => Zend\Router\Http\Literal::class,
        'options' => [
            'route'    => '/index/foo',
            'defaults' => [
                'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                'action'     => 'foo',
            ],
        ],
        'may_terminate' => false,
        'child_routes' => [
            'myroute1get' => [// This child route will match GET request
                'type' => Method::class,
                'options' => [
                    'verb' => 'get',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'foo'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'myroute1post' => [// This child route will match POST request
                'type' => Method::class,
                'options' => [
                    'verb' => 'post',
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => 'bar'
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        ],
    ],
    //...
];
```

Comment: You just saved my hours. salute!

Comment: Would we still be able to call like `$this->url("myroute1", ["action"=>"foo"])` and `$this->url("myroute1", ["action"=>"bar"])` ? Or we would have to specify child route name

Comment: @AliRasheed I'm not sure which one might work or maybe even both of them work, but anyway, it doesn't matter, because both of them should have the same URL, the difference is only *how the **application** routes to **action** by **method** used*

Comment: @AliRasheed by the way, you don't need to pass 2nd parameter, so `$this->url('myroute1')` is enough

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but I wanted to share my answer for anyone who comes across this and is struggling with zend or Laminas (I use Laminas) and the routing of method based AND localized routes. Basically you should be able to just replace "Laminas" by "Zend" for the namespaces. The code base is very similar.

First of all: **I was not able to use @evilReiko's solution** because `'may_terminate' => false,` always threw an exception for me. When I set it to `true` the child routes were ignored ... obviously  :D

But the note helped me to understand some stuff going on. I decided to just implement a custom class which handles both: URL localization and method/action routing.

I created a new folder `Classes` and added a new file `MethodSegment` into `modules/Application`.
So the file path would be `modules/Application/Classes/MethodSegment.php`.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Classes;

use Laminas\Router\Exception;
use Laminas\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Laminas\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Laminas\Router\Http\RouteMatch;
use Traversable;
    
/**
 * Method route.
 */
class MethodSegment extends \Laminas\Router\Http\Segment
{
    /**
     * associative array [method => action]
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $methodActions;

    /**
     * Default values - accessing $defaults from parent class Segment
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $defaults;

    /**
     * Create a new method route
     *
     * @param  string $route
     * @param  array  $constraints
     * @param  array  $defaults
     */
    public function __construct($route, array $constraints = [], array $defaults = [])
    {
        if(is_array($defaults['action']))
        {
            $this->methodActions = $defaults['action'];
            $defaults['action'] = array_values($defaults['action'])[0];
        }

        parent::__construct($route, $constraints, $defaults);
    }

    /**
     * factory(): defined by RouteInterface interface.
     *
     * @see    \Laminas\Router\RouteInterface::factory()
     *
     * @param  array|Traversable $options
     * @return Method
     * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public static function factory($options = [])
    {
        if ($options instanceof Traversable) {
            $options = ArrayUtils::iteratorToArray($options);
        } elseif (! is_array($options)) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
                '%s expects an array or Traversable set of options',
                __METHOD__
            ));
        }

        if (! isset($options['defaults'])) {
            $options['defaults'] = [];
        }

        return new static($options['route'] ?? null, $options['constraints'] ?? [], $options['defaults']);
    }

    /**
     * match(): defined by RouteInterface interface.
     *
     * @see    \Laminas\Router\RouteInterface::match()
     *
     * @return RouteMatch|null
     */
    public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null, array $options = [])
    {
        if (! method_exists($request, 'getMethod')) {
            return null;
        }

        $requestVerb = strtolower($request->getMethod());
        $verb = array_keys($this->methodActions);

        if (in_array($requestVerb, $verb)) {
            $this->defaults['action'] = $this->methodActions[$requestVerb];
            return parent::match($request, $pathOffset, $options);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically I copied the code from the Laminas Method class and enhanced it so I can pass an array of actions.

You can use the MethodSegment like so:

```
use App\Routing\MethodSegment;
return [
    'router' => [
        'routes' => [
            'home' => [
                'type'    => MethodSegment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route'    => /[:language/],
                    'constraints' => [...],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\IndexController::class,
                        'action'     => [
                            'get' => 'index',
                            'post' => 'postIndex', // e.g. form
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
      [...]
```

Hope this helps anyone, IMO the child route approach is very clunky.